# How to export data from multiple data frames and store it in a text file with specific format

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I have two Dataframes as described here:
[image]

[image]

And I want to create a file from both of these dataframes like below.

```
NR
NR^AI123456^AABC International PVT.Ltd^A1234^A526
Address^AXYZ,1234,Industrial Estate^A123^A
NR^I123457^ABC1 International PVT.Ltd^A1236^A529
Address^AXYZ,1235,Industrial Estate^A129^A
NR^AI123458^AABC2 International PVT.Ltd^A1238^A1000
Address^AXYZ,1236,Industrial Estate^A129^A
```

Can anybody help me how to create one file with sequential column values added from the table separated by `^A` using Pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dataframes are following this pattern:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"nr": ["nr1", "nr2", "nr3"], "name": ["name1", "name2", "name3"], "id": ["id1", "id2", "id3"], "bal": ["bal1", "bal2", "bal3"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"add": ["add1", "add2", "add3"], "house no": ["house no1", "house no2", "house no3"], "add add": ["add add1", "add add2", "add add3"]})
```

If you wanted to write them to a single output row per input row, you could achieve that with:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True).stack().groupby(level=0).apply("^A".join).to_csv(header=False, index=False)
```

But your question calls for the records from the two dataframes to be interleaved, in which case a relatively straightforward way of doing it would be:

```
x = df1.stack().groupby(level=0).apply("^A".join).values.tolist()
y = df2.stack().groupby(level=0).apply("^A".join).values.tolist()

f = open('test.txt', 'w')

for i, z in enumerate(x):
    f.write(f"NR^A{z}\n")
    f.write(f"Address^A{y[i]}\n")

f.close()
```

The resulting output file follows the format in your question:

```
NR^Anr1^Aname1^Aid1^Abal1
Address^Aadd1^Ahouse no1^Aadd add1
NR^Anr2^Aname2^Aid2^Abal2
Address^Aadd2^Ahouse no2^Aadd add2
NR^Anr3^Aname3^Aid3^Abal3
Address^Aadd3^Ahouse no3^Aadd add3
```